# How to test mat-select components with karma

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine

my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'p-dropdown',
  template: `
<mat-form-field *ngIf="settings">
  <mat-select [value]="settings.selected" [compareWith]="compareFn" [placeholder]="placeholder">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of settings.options" [value]="option"> {{option.name}} </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

my test:

```
fdescribe('Drodown Component', () => {
  let component: TestHostComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestHostComponent, DropdownComponent],
      imports:[materialModule,BrowserAnimationsModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  })); 
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  fit('should show placeholder', () => {
    const el: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const p = el.querySelector('.mat-form-field-label');
    expect(p.textContent).toEqual('name2');
  });
});
@Component({
  selector: `host-component`,
  template: `<p-dropdown [settings]="settings"></p-dropdown>`
})
class TestHostComponent {
  settings = {options:[{_id:1,name:'name1'}, {_id:2,name:'name2'}], selected:{_id:2,name:'name2'}}
}
```

'p-dropdown' work well in serve, but for some reason, not work in my testing.
In debug, i can see the p-dropdown setting as well, so i don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, please mention that

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Comment: You can actually inspect your output HTML. Can you make sure that an element with class `mat-form-field-label` exists?

Comment: if i set the placeholder, than it have. but it is not the point, there is no options at all.